# Is $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} f(x_{0} + \frac{1}{n}) = \lim\limits_{h \to 0^{+}} f(x_{0} + h) \triangleq f(x_{0}^{+})$?

Tags: calculus, probability-distributions

We know in probability, the cumulative distribution function is right continuous. The proof of this statement used a relation that 
$$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} F_{X}\left(x_{0} + \frac{1}{n}\right) = \lim\limits_{h \to 0^{+}} F_{X}(x_{0} + h) \triangleq F_{X}(x_{0}^{+})$$
However, I do not know why this is true? Or is it true in general or only for CDF's?

Comment: The middle limit (with $h$) implies the first (with $n$), but the first limit does *not* imply the second limit.

Comment: If you define it as the integral of the density function then you would need a rather badly behaving density for it to not be continous after integration.

Comment: What about discrete random variable?

Answer (score 0):

It is not true in general. For CDFs it is true because
\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to \infty} F_X\left(x+\frac{1}{n}\right)&=\lim_{n\to \infty}\mathrm{Pr}\left(X \le x+\frac{1}{n}\right)\\&=\mathrm{Pr}\left(\bigcap_n (X\le x+\frac{1}{n})\right)\\
& =\mathrm{Pr}\left(X\le x\right)=F_X(x).
\end{align}

Comment: I see. It makes sense now. Thanks.